# Server to Server Communication using HTTPS/SSL

Tags: https

I have two servers which exchanges information using HTTP/Rest Protocol.  Now I want to secure the communication between these two servers.  So I planned to implement the information exchange over **HTTPS**/Rest.
Is this possible? if possible please provide me some examples.

*Info : I am using Apache Httpd on CentOS.*
Thank you
Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: I believe you should post it on serverfault.com

Comment: Your question is rather vague, but you might be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8952840/372643